# Cannot connect to kafka docker container from outside client (wurstmeister images)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile, docker-machine, kafka-python

There are so many answers for this question that I ended up being totally confused about how I can connect to Kafka docker container from an outside client.

I have created two docker machines, a manager and a worker with these commands:

```
docker-machine create manager
docker-machine create worker1
```

I have add these two nodes inside a docker swarm.

```
docker@manager:~$ docker node ls                                                                                                                                                                             
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
6bmovp3hr0j2w5irmexvvjgzq *   manager             Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.5
mtgbd9bg8d6q0lk9ycw10bxos     worker1             Ready               Active                                  19.03.5
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "hostname | awk -F'-' '{print $$2}'"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

From inside docker, everything works fine. I can create topics and then produce/consume messages.

I created a python script in order to consume messages from outside docker. The simple code is presented below:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

try:
    print('Welcome to parse engine')
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('streams-plaintext-input', bootstrap_servers='manager:9094')
    for message in consumer:
        print(message)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # Logs the error appropriately. 
    pass
```

But the code is stack forever. The connection is not correct. Can anyone provide any help on how to setup a connection?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `docker-machine` you have to either

1. Run your code also in a container (using `kafka:9092`)
2. Run your code within the VM OS (using `vm-host-name:9094`)
3. Add `PLAINTEXT://localhost:9096` to the advertised listeners, expose 9096 from the VM to your host, then use `localhost:9096` in your code (note: 9096 is some random port)

---

The gist is that clients must be able to connect to the bootstrap address **and** the advertised one that is being returned. If it cannot connect to the second, code will timeout.

Comment: can you please help me with third step? I am not sure that I understand how to do this.

Comment: If I execute kafkacat -L -b manager:9094 from my local machine it works. Why python script does not return anything but it stuck? I am confused